Xcode - ITMS-90111: Unsupported SDK or Xcode version
When I try to upload an app to the AppStore, I receive following feedback:

I had Xcode 16 with visionOS installed. Because of the feedback, I switched back to Xcode 15.3 with visionOs 1.0. I archived it again and tried to upload the app again. But I still receive the same feedback. Did the same with Xcode 15.4 and visionOs 1.2.

I also tried App Store refuses my update after installing Xcode 11 beta with keeping Xcode 10.2, but it seems that there is no such property for visionOS in the info.plist
I do not have any further ideas...
When I open the build in TestFlight, it also shows that the SDK is of visionOs 1.2. Xcode 15.4 is also fine. And it says that the binary file was checked. In the distribution error, it shows that it is a binary file error.

My macOS version: 15.0

This problem was caused by macOS 15.0, which I already installed. It did not matter, which xCode version I used. So I organized a cloud access to a Mac (with macOS Sonoma and xCode 15.4) (https://www.macincloud.com), cloned the project from GitHub and archived and sent it to Apple Store connect again.
Now, was able to send it to Apple to check it.

When you've got the build archived through Xcode 15.4 do the following:

From Archives, right click the build, Show in Finder
Right click, Show Package Contents
Products -> Applications -> Right click "App Name", Show Package Contents
Find the Info.plist and open in Xcode
Change BuildMachineOSBuild value to be the latest non-beta MacOS Release, you can find it here - e.g 23G93
Save
Distribute normally


I ran into a similar thing, briefly, with Xcode 15.4, ITMS-90512. It was an App Store Connect or app processing issue. It has cleared for me now, using Xcode 15.4. And after I opened a Feedback, I eventually received an email from DTS that the issue had been resolved.
I suggest you file a Feedback (http://feedbackassistant.apple.com). Also do a complete nuke-derived-data build and archive, and try again.
DTS is not currently accepting new tickets/requests. They're instead routing everything to Apple Dev Forums for another week or two. So perhaps raise the issue on the Apple Dev Forums.

I sent some feedback.
I tried it with derived data, but it does not solve the problem.
It seems that more people have exactly the same problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756859?answerId=791282022#791282022

The problem seems to be resolved
We managed to submit the same builds again yesterday from Mac OS 15 RC without any rejection.
